# Upload git config changes to server

Tags: git, git-config

Wanna to update git configurations on server like aliases

```
$ git config --local alias.myalias myvalue
$ git push
```

after that cloning project and can't find the *myalias* key

```
$ git config --local alias.myalias
```

gave me nothing (nothing in *.git/config* file). How can I *push* my *.git/config* to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config ( at .git/config) is local to your repo and cannot be pushed. Only thing you can do probably is to checkin a file like `.gitconfig` in the repo and setup a symlink to the .git/config in other repos that you use.